# Difference between Encoding::BINARY and Encoding::ASCII-8BIT?

Tags: ruby, encoding

Ruby says that `Encoding::BINARY` and `Encoding::ASCII-8BIT` are the same.

```
Encoding::BINARY == Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
#=> true
```

We explicitly create a binary string and ruby still says it's `ASCII_8BIT`.

```
String.new("ABC", encoding: Encoding::BINARY).encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Likewise, `force_encoding` cannot create a `BINARY`, it just creates an `ASCII-8BIT` string.

It seems that `BINARY` is simply an alias for `ASCII-8BIT`. Are there any differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation is correct: `BINARY` and `ASCII-8BIT` are indeed aliases and being an alias implies there are no differences as it's just another name for the same encoding, method, etc.

Looking at the source code is the most reliable way to confirm this. CRuby's character encodings can be found in the [`enc`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_5_0/enc) directory. The `ASCII-8BIT` encoding is defined in the [`ascii.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/enc/ascii.c) file containing the following line ([in 2.5.0, it's line 61](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/enc/ascii.c#L61)):

```
ENC_ALIAS("BINARY", "ASCII-8BIT")
```

`ENC_ALIAS` works like Ruby's `alias` keyword (alias, original name).

Confirming that `BINARY` or another encoding name is an alias can be done in pure Ruby too. One possibility is calling the `Encoding.aliases` method which returns a hash (alias => original):

```
Encoding.aliases['BINARY']  # => "ASCII-8BIT"
```

Other useful methods are `Encoding#name` which returns the original name and `Encoding#names` which also returns all aliases:

```
Encoding::BINARY.names    # => ["ASCII-8BIT", "BINARY"]
Encoding::US_ASCII.names  # => ["US-ASCII", "ASCII", "ANSI_X3.4-1968", "646"]
```

Or a way without any `Encoding` methods:

```
Encoding::BINARY.equal?(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
```

As the `==` method is often overwritten and may return `true` even if both operands are two different objects, `BasicObject#equal?` should be called to check if they are the same object. E.g. `1` and `1.0` have the same value (`==` returns `true`) but not the same object identity (`equal?` returns `false`).

Comment: I was trying to find where those constants were defined, but I was expecting them to show up in the ruby "stubs" that come with my IDE, and I didn't think to look in the C source. Thanks!

Comment: May I edit the answer to start with “No” rather than “Yes” as the question is “Are there any differences?” and the answer is “there are no differences”?

Comment: @MartinDorey: I've rephrased it but if you still want to improve the beginning or any other part of the answer feel free to do it.